# Choose rows a fixed time-interval apart in Datetime-indexed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, variables

I have a pandas dataframe indexed by DateTime from hour "00:00:00" until hour "23:59:00" (increments by minute, seconds not counted).

```
in: df.index
out: DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-08 00:00:00', '2018-10-08 00:00:00',
           '2018-10-08 00:00:00', '2018-10-08 00:00:00',
           '2018-10-08 00:00:00', '2018-10-08 00:00:00',
           '2018-10-08 00:00:00', '2018-10-08 00:00:00',
           '2018-10-08 00:00:00', '2018-10-08 00:00:00',
           ...
           '2018-10-08 23:59:00', '2018-10-08 23:59:00',
           '2018-10-08 23:59:00', '2018-10-08 23:59:00',
           '2018-10-08 23:59:00', '2018-10-08 23:59:00',
           '2018-10-08 05:16:00', '2018-10-08 07:08:00',
           '2018-10-08 13:58:00', '2018-10-08 09:30:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', length=91846, freq=None)
```

Now I want to choose specific intervals, say every 1 minute, or every 1 hour, starting from "00:00:00" and retrieve all the rows that interval apart consecutively.

I can grab entire intervals, say the first hour interval, with

```
df.between_time("01:00:00","00:00:00")
```

But I want to be able to

(a) get only all the times that are a specific intervals apart
(b) get all the 1-hour intervals without having to manually ask for them 24 times. How do I increment the DatetimeIndex inside the between_time command? Is there a better way than that?

Comment: Why do you need individual data frames?  Why not just subset the original data frame using `.iloc` or `.loc`?  Can you group the data?

Comment: I answered based on the somewhat generic question, but you might have a more specific problem. It would be helpful to post what you tried and your expected outputs. Check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Polkaguy6000 Thanks, I think your answer would be a good approach, I'm going to try it. I haven't asked this carefully enough I'll try to redefine exactly what I'm trying to do and edit this to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem with masking rather than making new dataframes. For example you can add a column `df['which_one']` and set different numbers for each subset. Then you can access the subset by calling `df[df['which_one']==x]` where `x` is the subset you want to select. You can still do other conditional statements and just about everything else that Pandas had to offer by access the data this way.

P.S. There are other methods to access data that might be faster. I just used what I'm most comfortable with another way would be `df[df['which_one'].eq(x)]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deadset on dataframes I would suggest doing so with a dictionary of dataframes such as:

```
import pandas as pd

dfdict={}

for i in range(0,10):
    dfdict[i]=pd.DataFrame()

print(dfdict)
```

as you will see they are indeed dfs

```
out[1]
{0: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 1: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 2: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 3: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 4: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 5: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 6: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 7: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 8: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 9: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []}
```

Although as others have suggested there might be a more practical approach to solve your problem (difficult to say without more specifics of the issue)